# 'Page Not Found' bug for Tag Info Page

Tags: discussion, bug

I suggested a tag wiki edit for [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) (at least, I *think* it was this one, not sure..), and I went to the [wiki page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/status-planned/info) today to see if my edit was applied (I normally don't get a notification when a tag wiki edit is accepted), and saw a completely different wiki 'About'.

I then tried to visit the 'tag revisions' page, only to find that it pointed to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts//revisions, resulting in a 'page not found' error.
I noticed that this same error happens when trying to visit the 'excerpt history', which leads me to suspect I found a bug in the Stack Exchange platform.

Can this be confirmed as a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag you tried to edit is a special [moderator-only tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47640/167646).

When no questions remain with the tag, after a certain amount of time the tag is deleted from the system. The wiki page is then [orphaned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62536/167646), and can be manually cleaned up by the developers/moderators. For these special tags, when the tag is once again added, its excerpt and wiki contents are automatically set by the software.

So, making changes to the tag excerpt or wiki is useless.

<sub>The actual implementation details may differ, this is just an educated guess.</sub>