# Seems like the 'status-review' meta tag has a broken excerpt history

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, meta-tags

If you go to [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)'s tag wiki and select "excerpt history", you go to this page: [`https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts//revisions`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts//revisions).  This is a 404.

It's odd that a tag wiki page would give a 404 like that.

Comment: Hmm. There's no post number attached to the wiki or the excerpt. Compare, e.g. [meta-tag:support]'s wiki [`http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/250430/revisions`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/250430/revisions)

Comment: This is now [meta-tag:status-norepro]; animuson made an edit.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Alrighty then.  Still odd that this could happen in the first place.

Comment: I think that was just the pre-filled text that associates the tag as the "default" since it always exists, and the tag wiki had never been officially created. All I did was click edit and then Save Edits and it created everything fine.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Just noticed that this same issue applies to other sites.  It isn't that much of a bug here, but on several other sites (eg on [SuperUser](http://meta.superuser.com/tags)), several of them are broken like this.

Comment: Since it appears on other sites, I've opened [this on meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242167/default-tag-wikis-for-the-status-meta-tags-404-on-viewing-excerpt-history).

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273139/page-not-found-bug-for-tag-info-page

Answer (score 11):

This has been "fixed" as [@animuson ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) has made an edit.  It now goes to [`https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/274599/revisions`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/274599/revisions).

However, the root issue has not yet been fixed and appears on other sites.  See [this post on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242167/default-tag-wikis-for-the-status-meta-tags-404-on-viewing-excerpt-history).

Comment: This question is a duplicate of one I asked a week before you asked this one: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273139/page-not-found-bug-for-tag-info-page.